# http.post angular 2 not call webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-http

I try to call the api, the API is not triggered, I have no return error.
I'm using angular 5, and asp.net mvc 5, the api works normaly when triggered by postman. no have idea, what is the problem, can you help me? I am beginer on angular and webapi.

See my angular service:

```
@Injectable()
    export class LoginService {

      private urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:51871/Api/Login/Login';
      headers: Headers = new Headers ({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
      options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

      constructor(private http: Http)  { 

      }

      ValidarLogin(credenciais: Credenciais): Observable<RetornoAutenticacao[]>{

        let body = JSON.stringify(credenciais);

        return this.http.post(this.urlPrefix, body, this.options )
        .map((response: Response) => <RetornoAutenticacao[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

     handleError(error: Response) {
              console.error(error);
              return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
          }
    }
```

see my class model:

```
export class RetornoAutenticacao{
   UsuarioAtenticado : Boolean;
   Mensagem : string;
}

export class Credenciais{
    login: string;
    senha: string;
}
```

see my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login: string = 'teste';
  senha: string = 'teste';
  credenciais: Credenciais = new  Credenciais();
  menssagem: Observable<RetornoAutenticacao[]>;
  text:any;
  constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) { 


  }


  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    this.credenciais.login = this.login
    this.credenciais.senha = this.senha
    this.menssagem = this._loginService.ValidarLogin(this.credenciais);
    this.text = this.menssagem[1];

  }

  ngOnchange()
  {
    this.credenciais.login = this.login
    this.credenciais.senha = this.senha
    this.menssagem = this._loginService.ValidarLogin(this.credenciais);
    this.text = this.menssagem[1];

  }
}
```

Comment: Like Ojas pointed out, with observables if you don't call the subscribe method, the action is not triggered. So you need to call .subscribe on that observable to actually trigger the http call.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Component, Try this

```
this.menssagem = this._loginService.ValidarLogin(this.credenciais)
  .subscribe(
    res => { 
      console.log(res);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Comment: i try it, but i get this error: file: 
 'Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<RetornoAutenticacao>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.'

Answer (score 0):

that's it work for me:

```
 ValidarLogin(credenciais: Credenciais): Observable<RetornoAutenticacao>{

    let body = JSON.stringify(credenciais);

    return this.http.post(this.urlPrefix, body, this.options)
    .map(res => res.json()).catch(err => Observable.throw(this.handleError(err)))
}

 handleError(error: Response) {
          console.log(error)
          return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
      }
}
```

and component

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login: string = 'teste';
  senha: string = 'teste';
  credenciais: Credenciais = new  Credenciais();
  private menssagem: RetornoAutenticacao = new RetornoAutenticacao();

  constructor(
    private _loginService: LoginService,
    private http: Http) {}

  getLogin() {
    this._loginService.ValidarLogin(this.credenciais).subscribe(resp =>  this.menssagem ={ Menssagem: resp['Menssagem'] ,
    UsuarioAtenticado: resp['UsuarioAtenticado']

  });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    this.credenciais.login = this.login
    this.credenciais.senha = this.senha
     this.getLogin()

  }
  ngOnchange()
  {


  }
}
```